# What is the efficient way to pass value from other class to Main class, in JAVA?

Tags: java

I have in main class:

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Thread timeCheckThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                while (!done) {
                    System.out.println("Running!!");
                    System.out.println();
                    currentDate = LocalDate.now();
                    if (!oldDate.equals(currentDate)) {
                        index++;
                        saveData();
                        System.out.println("Saved!");
                    }
                    currentThread().sleep(5000);
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    timeCheckThread.start();      

    stage = primaryStage;
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(root);
    stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);");

    Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 312, 212);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);

    Controller controller = loader.<Controller>getController();
    controller.registerStage(stage);
    stage.show();
}

//launch 'start'
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

and in Controller class:

```
public void exitButtonClicked() {
    Platform.exit();
}
```

I want to pass a boolean from method `exitButtonClicked` to the main class so that I can end the loop of `while(!done)`. What is the efficient approach to accomplish this? Is, having a `setter` for `done` in a main method, and invoking that `setter` from an instance of `Main` class in `Controller` class, a good method?

Comment: Seems you should think about implementing [Model View Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: @Ischuetze Thanks! I will look into it later. Seems like a broad concept, so I might need quite a bit of study on that subject.

Comment: It looks like done is a field of your main class. You can just use a setter, or reference it directly. The problem will be your 'sleep(5000)' so you will still end up waiting 5 seconds even after done has been changed.

Comment: You should add a javafx tag, because the structure is going to be somewhat specific since you are not explicitly creating an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. Your controller needs access to the variables, and you have a 5s sleep. One way to do it, without passing around an instance of your main class is to make a static utility method.

```
class Main extends Application{
    static volatile boolean done = false;
    static Thread timeCheckThread;
    static void applicationIsExiting(){
        done = true;
        timeCheckThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Then when you create the time check thread assign it to the static variable:

```
 timeCheckThread = new Thread() { ...
```

The method in your controller would have a call the utility method.

```
public void exitButtonClicked() {
    Platform.exit();
    Main.applicationIsExiting();
}
```

Comment: This approach looks better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a final class or interface with a boolean. Set/Get this boolean wherever you need.

```
public final class foo {
     public static boolean flag = false;
}
```

In your Controller Class:

```
foo.flag = true;
```

In your Main Class:

```
while(!foo.flag) {
     /* Do Something */
}
```

Comment: When I add in Controller Class:
`isDone.value = false;`

I got:
`Non-static field 'value' cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: Make value `static`. Example: `public static boolean value = false;`

Comment: I tried that too. When I did that, I got `Unknown Class`.

Comment: Is your class name `isDone`? And is it a final class? Could you please post the class here?

Comment: `package sample;

/**
 * Created by Snipester on 1/28/2016.
 */

public final class isDone {

    public static boolean value = false;

}
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101908/discussion-between-pratik-gamer-and-user2004685).

Comment: Will the change in `foo.flag` really be guaranteed to propagate to the other thread? Wouldn't the flag need to be `volatile`?

Comment: @Alderath doesn't have to be volatile, in my case.